# How can I link to a JavaScript file above the site folder in ColdFusion 10?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Here is the problem. The company I work for has a number of sites, and many of them use the same jQuery UI widgets, like datepicker. I would really like to have just one copy of each widget in an _javascript folder on the top level of the server. The problem is that because the code is outside of the site folder, I need to use ColdFusion mappings to point to it. Apparently you can't use these with script or link tags however. It doesn't expand the mapping. So I tried using "ExpandPath" and got a message that it doesn't have permission to access that resource. Some research turned up that JavaScript can't access files on local file systems because that would be a security hole. So, although it was ugly, I tried wrapping the CSS file in  tags and the JS file in  tags, and then included them with cfinclude. That worked- sort of. The main issue is that apparently the css uses relative links to link to the images used, and those are all broken because the JS is included on a page in another folder from the script and images themselves.

Here is my question. Is there any good solution here? I don't think that what I want to do is unreasonable, but should I give up and just keep a copy of the widgets in every site folder? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Included javascript files, like CSS files, don't have to be touched at all by the ColdFusion processor. You just use ColdFusion to craft the link and feed it to the browser like you would any image, attachment, or link to another site. The only difference is that this link is in a `<script` tag.  So if you have several sites and want to access a common /js directory on all of them the work has to be done in the web server itself (IIS/Apache).

In your web server of choice make a virtual directory (or symbolic link) to your javascript directory called `/js` (or whatever name you choose). Do this for all the sites, and you have one /js directory that is accessible from all the hosted domains.

Comment: This looks like this will solve my problem, thanks! I hadn't been familiar with virtual directories before. I looked up how to do it, and it appears that you need to have direct access to the ColdFusion folder on the server. Since I don't have access to this and would need to ask our tech guys to create the directory for me when they can get around to it, is there anyway to set up the virtual directory from CF Admin? (doesn't look like it)

Comment: If you want to use virtual directories, ask those who can set it up to do so.  If it takes awhile, it's worth it.

Comment: " direct access to the ColdFusion folder on the server." No, ColdFusion really has nothing to do with it. You could uninstall ColdFusion and your web server would still be able to serve up the javascript.  The web server (IIS/Apache/etc.) process needs access to the physical directory on the server that has the javascript files.  You are right that the tech guys can probably set this up for you.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is that all our ColdFusion work is intranet only.  While we only have a few sites, that is more than one. We also use a development server as opposed to having people develop on their hard drives.

The first thing we did was to create a mapping on "/" to point to a certain directory.  Let's say that it's c:\fred.  In c:\fred we have subdirectories named images, css, js, udf, etc.  That allows us to do stuff like this:

```
<cfinclude template = "/Templates/Reportheader.cfm">
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "/css/cashflow.css" title= "style1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/browserDetect.js" ></script>
```

in any application.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Dan, but unless I am missing something, this doesn't look any different than what I have already tried. Setting up a mapping to the JS folder didn't work. I found that you can use mappings with cfinclude but not script or link.

Comment: What you found is that you can't, but I can.  What you may have missed is that we mapped to a single character and did not try to expand the path.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but mapping "/" to a different location would not work for us, as we would still need "/" to point to the actual root of our site.